# Can I get a little integral help?

Tags: integration

Find the integral $$\int_0^3 \sqrt {y+1}\, dy$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: do you mean $\int_0^3 \sqrt{y+1} dy$?

Comment: if u mean that then the answer is so trivial, that $\int_0^3(y+1)^{\frac 1 2}dy=\frac  2 3 \left[(y+1)^{\frac 3 2}\right]_0^3=\frac {14}3$

Answer (score 4):

With substitution $x=y+1,\text dx=\text dy$ we have

$$\int_a^b\sqrt x\text dx=\left.\frac 23x^{3/2}\right|_a^b$$

Can you take it from here?  Note the change of variables requires a recalculation of the limits, or else a translation back to the original variable.

Comment: How did you get the 2/3 fraction

Comment: @13thoule13 Remember that $\sqrt x=x^{1/2}$ and that $$\int x^a\,\mathrm dx=\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}$$

Comment: Ok ...yes I can see that

Comment: Yes sir... I do remember that

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_0^{3} \sqrt{y+1} dy = \int_0^{3} (y+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}d (y + 1) = \frac{2}{3} \int_0^{3} \frac{3}{2}(y+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}d (y + 1) = \left. \frac{2}{3}(y+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} \right|_0^3 = \frac{2}{3} 4 ^{\frac{3}{2}} - \frac{2}{3}1^{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{16}{3} - \frac{2}{3} = \frac{14}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** substitute  $$u=(y+1)^{1.5}\Rightarrow du=1.5\sqrt{y+1}$$that gives the correct result